# iOS exploit re-using purchase receipts?

Tags: ios, architecture, in-app-purchase, backend, exploit

I think there's a potential way for users to get Apple in-app purchases for free, by sharing legitimate Apple receipts. I'd like to find a way to prevent this for my app. Check my logic -- here's the architecture:

1) There is a game app that stores users' purchases in an online database. For example, an items database tracks which Characters have a Magic Sword.

2) When a user purchases a Magic Sword IAP on an iOS client device (using the regular Apple methods), Apple generates a receipt and sends it to the client.

3) The client app then sends the receipt (securely) to a backend verification server for validation and to update the database.

4) The server verifies the receipt with Apple, and on success updates the database, setting the clients Character's possessions to include a Magic Sword.

All pretty standard.

What is stopping Evil Person A from logging in, and legitimately buying the Magic Sword, intercepting Apple's receipt, and handing it to his friend Evil Person B?

Evil Person B logs in (with some hacked client which still makes secure calls to the backend server, or a program that makes secure calls as if it were the client), makes the web request to verify the *same* Apple receipt, and receives the Magic Sword.

Evil Person C does the same, etc. etc.

In each case Apple will tell the verification server that the receipt is valid (it is!); the problem is the receipt doesn't belong to the user who is calling the server.

I can't think of a way to confirm that the receipt and the person asking for verification of the receipt belong to each other.

Android IAPs get around this problem by allowing a user payload to be specified at purchase time, and that value becomes part of the receipt. That can be used to link a receipt to a user.

The closest almost-fix I could come up with is maintaining a list of the uniqueIDs of each receipt that has been verified, and disallowing any attempt to verify a receipt on this list. But then we run into problems with Restore Purchases, Plus, I haven't seen anything from Apple recommending receipt tracking as a best practice.

Am I way off base here? Is there a better way to architect the connections between the client app doing the purchasing, the backend server, Apple and the database? Or is this legit?

(edited for typo)

Comment: Hypothetically, I would imagine person B and C etc would all need person A's Apple ID at minimum.

Comment: At a minimum, receipts from Apple have unique transaction ids that can be stored in the apps backend server. The server just won't allow multiple uses of the same transaction id.

Comment: @Bamsworld -- unfortunately, no. The receipt to be validated is just a string that you pass to Apple via a webservice -- it doesn't have to come from a device or with an AppleID attached.

Comment: @ChrisPrince -- that's probably the way to do it. I wonder why Apple doesn't mention that it's a necessary precaution, and if you don't do it you can be taken advantage of.  Good thing I'm not an Evil Person, or I'd be all over this!